# SSL certificate verification issue when accessing multiple API endpoints behind a firewall - Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, azure-functions, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm working behind a firewall, and my code needs to interact with several API endpoints. However, I consistently encounter an SSL error (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)'))). To bypass this error, I manually download the certificate from each endpoint and add it to the path using **`os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = "path to certificate"`**.

The problem arises when I have multiple endpoints. Lets say I want to access azure cosmos db and azure storage account in the same code, If I try adding multiple paths like **`os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] ='path to cert 1; path to cert 2'`**, it doesn't work. Similarly, if I keep all the required certificates in a folder and add the path to the folder using **`os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] ='path to cert folder'`**, it still doesn't work.

I'm looking for a solution to handle this problem of SSL certificate verification when accessing multiple API endpoints behind a firewall. Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.